# ImportError when trying to import plot from dataprep.eda

Tags: python, dataprep

I recently swap from window based pc to a macbookair m2. Now I'm trying to use the plot from dataprep but is not working and giving me several errors (it used to work correctly in windows).

This is the code I'm using:
%pip install dataprep
import dataprep
from dataprep.eda import plot

I get this error after running the third line 'from dataprep.eda import plot':

ImportError: cannot import name 'Ttest_1sampResult' from 'scipy.stats.stats'

At the begining the error was different but as I try to solve it by updating packes and staff, this is the last error I encounter (all related with running the third line from dataprep.eda import plot'.

I have tried unstailling scipy and reinstalling it again, downgrading and updating it but nothings work.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

What is your scipy version? According to this [link](https://github.com/pystatgen/sgkit/issues/1016), the same error would be fixed with scipy<1.10, can you try installing this version of scipy and check if the error appears again?